# Compile error with constexpr functions (visual studio 2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c++14, constexpr

I am trying to compile the following piece of code in Visual Studio 2015 (Community version) but encountering the error shown further down below.

```
/*****Source Code Start*******/
constexpr char const* GetStatusAsCString(Status compute)
{
    switch (compute)
    {
        case armnn::Status::Success: return "Status::Success";
        case armnn::Status::Failure: return "Status::Failure";
        default:                     return "Unknown";
    }
}
/*****Source Code End*******/
```

Error message:

```
> Error (active)        a constexpr function must contain exactly one return
> statement ArmNN_MnistTF_64b   c:\armnn\armnn-devenv\armnn\include\armnn\TypesUtils.hpp    22
```

Note that i have made sure of the following settings:

1. Set the compiler front end as Clang in VS 2015:

[image]

2. I have set the C++ standard as C++14.

Can anyone please advise me on what else am I missing? Been struggling with this error for sometime now.

Comment: I suppose that Visual Studio 2015 doesn't completely support C++14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 does not fully implement C++14 even as of VS 2015 Update 3 although it has a lot of it.

Specifically, [N3652 Extended constexpr](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html) is not implemented until VS 2017. You should upgrade to the latest VS 2017 Community edition update (which at this point is [15.7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2018/05/07/vs-2017-15-7-update/))

See [Visual C++ Language Conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance)